# Can GD pick the depth of interlacing in a progressive JPEG?

Tags: php, gd, jpeg

I know using [`imageinterlace`](http://php.net/imageinterlace) it's possible to create a progressive image, but I need to know if's possible to actually ask for a specific step in progression. Say if the Jpeg file is created using 3 levels scan, would I be able to downgrade that to only level 2 or 1?

Comment: Can you name a few programs that let you pick the depth of the interlacing? I've never seen this option before.

Comment: @Charles, not that I know of, but I'm writing a client software that doesn't allow real-time streaming, I only get the image when is fully downloaded, missing all progressive stages, hence, I needed to know If I could manually download each depth. thanks

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like this is a thing you can actually control when building a JPEG.

From [Wikipedia's article on JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Entropy_coding):

> Baseline JPEG also supports progressive encoding. While sequential encoding encodes coefficients of a single block at a time (in a zigzag manner), progressive encoding encodes similar-positioned coefficients of all blocks in one go, followed by the next positioned coefficients of all blocks, and so on. So, if the image is divided into N 8×8 blocks {B0,B1,B2, ..., Bn-1}, then progressive encoding encodes Bi(0,0) for all blocks, i.e., for all i = 0, 1, 2, ..., N-1. This is followed by encoding Bi(0,1) coefficient of all blocks, followed by Bi(1,0)-th coefficient of all blocks, then Bi(2,0)-th coefficient of all blocks, and so on. It should be noted here that once all similar-positioned coefficients have been encoded, the next position to be encoded is the one occurring next in the zigzag traversal as indicated in [the figure above](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aJPEG_ZigZag.svg).

Given the description, there is no way to actually control the nature of JPEG interlacing.  The number of passes is part of the standard and the image format itself.

It is similarly uncontrollable in [most other image formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_(bitmaps)), most of which also expressly call out one and only one interlacing formula in their standards, with the exception of TGA, which has two.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop allows you to choose the number of scans (3,4,or 5) on progressive JPEG.

imageinterlace has the $interlace value as an int not a bool which makes me wonder if a value > 0 isn't just enabling it but choosing the number of scans. The manual does not confirm this, but it may be worth a try.

Also I do not know if below 3 or above 5 exist as far as scan counts. In which case, you'd think they'd HAVE to mention it so you wouldn't choose 1 as the value... But who knows. I may play with it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG images are not actually interlaced. Progressive JPEG allows you to break the DC coefficient and the range of AC coefficients down for each 8x8 block of data. This refines the data but each scan applies to all pixels (unlike actual interlacing).

JPEG allows you to specify the number of scans for a progressive image. The JPEG terminology is "Spectral Selection". In the case of AC coefficients, you also have flexibility in ordering the scans.

The problem is that JPEG has so much flexibility here that it is difficult to create a programming or user interface that would allow you to take advantage all this flexibility.

There has to be at least 2 scans per component (otherwise it would not be progressive).